# How to check if particular array number exists in second array in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build a fast, pseudo random number generator, with unique numbers, but with a twist.  The numbers picked are from a progressively increasing sample set,i.e. (1-20) then (2-21)...but with my limited coding experience, I am getting some duplicates.  Using Google Script, is there a way of checking if a particular array element exists in another array?

```
  function temp3() {
var ss = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet6");
 var range = ss.getRange("b14:av14");
 var m = 0

 var picks = [];

 for(var j = 1; j < 48; j++) {
  var array1 = [1+m, 2+m, 3+m, 4+m, 5+m, 6+m, 7+m, 8+m, 9+m, 10+m, 
11+m, 12+m, 13+m, 14+m, 15+m, 16+m, 17+m, 18+m, 19+m, 20+m];

  shuffleArray(array1); 
  picks.push(array1[0]);

  m = m + 1
 }
   ss.getRange(16, 2, 1, 47).setValues([picks]); 
}
```

Comment: Google script is built upon JavaScript 1.6

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this but if you don't want to modify your current approach too much, add a separate function that checks if picks already contains your number. If it does drop the first element and run the function again. If not, add to picks.

```
function temp3() {
    var ss = 
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet6");
    var range = ss.getRange("b14:av14");
    var m = 0
    var picks = [];
    for (var j = 1; j < 48; j++) {
        var array1 = [1+m, 2+m, 3+m, 4+m, 5+m, 6+m, 7+m, 8+m,
                      9+m, 10+m, 11+m, 12+m, 13+m, 14+m, 15+m,
                      16+m, 17+m, 18+m, 19+m, 20+m];
        shuffleArray(array1); 
        picks = addToPicks(array1,picks)
        m = m + 1
    }
    ss.getRange(16, 2, 1, 47).setValues([picks]); 
}

function addToPicks(arr,picks) {
    if (picks.indexOf(arr[0]) === -1) {
        picks.push(arr[0])
        return picks
    }
    arr.shift();
    return addToPicks(arr,picks);
}
```

You could also do this check in your shuffleArray function.

By the way, instead of calling your shuffleArray function try checking out [Math.random's documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) There's an example there of a function that generates a random integer between two numbers, which might be more helpful to you than shuffling an array.

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Comment: I noticed that you replaced  my line with "push" with ; picks = addToPicks(array1,picks).  This seems to work, but how?  I can not seem to find addToPicks anywhere?

Comment: I define addToPicks in the code above. U trolling me bro?

Comment: No, I'm just a novice to Google script.  I saw my error after sending, sorry.  But I am trying to loop through this, in other words =,I want to run "temp3" 10 times, but I don't know how to "reset" so that addToPicks starts from scratch each time.